# Can Jasmine create new properties on object and remove them afterwards?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have to spy on a currently not existing property on a global object for a spec. The global object's property in this spec is accessed outside of the spec by the functionality tested. For good test isolation, I want the mocked property to be removed at the end of that spec. As I don't want to keep track of this, I want it to be deleted automatically after the spec, just like jasmine removes spies created with spyOn. I tried to use `spyOnProperty`, which just gets me a `property does not exist` error. Here's the code:

```js
describe('test', function () {
  const value = "value"
  const test = {};

  it('should create automatically deleted property on object', function () {
    spyOnProperty(test, "key", "get").and.returnValue(value);
    /* In my code this is a complex call, accessing the global variable from outside: */
    expect(test.key).toBe(value)
  });
});
```

I know I could do the following, but that is error-prone (property must be manually deleted) and verbose:

```js
describe('test', function () {
  const value = "value"
  const test = {};

  it('manually creates and deletes property on object', function () {
    Object.defineProperty(test, 'key', {
      get: () => value,
      configurable: true
    });
    spyOnProperty(test, "key", "get").and.callThrough();
    /* In my code this is a complex call, accessing the global variable from outside: */
    expect(test.key).toBe(value);
    delete test.key;
  });
})
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0ftz6eq7/4/) is my fiddle.

Does jasmine provide a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If test isolation is your goal, you should isolate the object as a whole. You spotted the right problem, but now ask if this arbitrary library can provide a work around for it.

As I do not know your full scenario I can only name the two most likely options you can follow.

**Option 1 - Test Isolated Object**
Instead of having *const test = {};* in your describe block you can pull it into the it block. If you have more it-blocks and test is used over and over again, you can create another test object in this one it-block and only add your property to this object

```js
describe('test', function () {
  const value = "value"
  const test = {};

  it('manually creates and deletes property on object', function () {
    //replace with your construction logic
    const anotherTest = {};
    //replace value with your actual method call
    anotherTest.key = value;
    expect(anotherTest.key).toBe(value);
  });
})
```

Since no one else uses the object, your test object is isolated and other tests are not affected.

**Option 2 - Before Each**
Instead of creating your object directly in the describe, add a beforeEach in the describe, where you create it.

```js
describe('test', function () {

  const value = "value"
  const test;

  beforeEach( function() {
    //new object created before each it()-block, overwriting the previous test object
    test = {};
  }

  it('manually creates and deletes property on object', function () {
    test.key = value;
    expect(test.key).toBe(value);
  });
})
```

There is no need for spies to manage object life cycles. As the name implies, a spy is supposed to look at the thing, not to interact with it. The moment you want the spy to "change something", you are violating its contract.

Comment: Great answer. I have a strong preference for the first option. Tests should be Readable, Isolated, Thorough, and Explicit (RITE way). Explicit means that everything you need to understand a test gets defined inside the scope of that test. beforeEach and afterEach violate that principle, making tests that rely on them harder to fully understand.

Comment: You cannot generalize it this way. BeforeEach adds complexity, but when you have 20 it()-blocks, copy pasting the same code in every block is not just unreadable, but a maintenance nightmare. The goal of all these principles is to reduce maintenance effort. Copy pasting usually increases it instead.

Comment: Sorry for not being as explicit, as I maybe should have been. The global object, lies completely outside of my scope and is used from internal logic, which is called from the spec. This may seem less than beautiful, but I have no access to this part of the code. The expectation in my example is a just placeholder for that.

Comment: I also do not agree completely with your conclusion: A spy in jasmine does interact with the logic, as it can be configured to return a value of your choice. This is important, to allow targeted testing of a code area (e.g. you want to test the code in your "else"-logic, so you return false). This is, what I try to achieve here.

Comment: You need to be careful with wording here. In testing you have spies, stubs, and mocks. Jasmine might do you a disservice by putting it all together, but there is a huge difference in how you handle each. Both Mocks and Stubs are rarely required in JS. Since you can create and override any object at any given time, they have no use here. This however goes far beyond your question. So please explain, what it is that you are missing.

Comment: @Xellos - you can encapsulate logic you would have done in beforeEach/afterEach into factory functions and clean up functions which you can call once each in each test. The difference between that and beforEach/afterEach is that you can explicitly see how the data is being created, and a factory can guarantee data isolation between different tests. You can both avoid duplication *and* make test dependencies explicit.

Comment: @Nils-o-mat "The global object, lies completely outside of my scope and is used from internal logic, which is called from the spec." - I'm not sure why that invalidates the provided answer. Say your real app code has a global called `foo`. What is preventing you from replacing that `foo` with your own `foo` in the context of a particular test and doing whatever you like with it?